# Angular2 EventEmitter from parent class

Tags: angular, typescript, events, inheritance

I created a abstract super class to handle generic factors for various form components within my app.

For some reason I cannot properly catch events emitted by a derived class who's `EventEmitter` is declared in a superclass.

**Superclass:**

```typescript
export abstract class Form<T> implements OnInit {
    @Output() submitted : EventEmitter<T> = new EventEmitter<T>();
    fb                  : FormBuilder     = new FormBuilder();
    formModel           : ControlGroup;

    abstract ngOnInit() : any;
}
```

**Derived:**

```typescript
export class LoginFormComponent extends Form<Login> {

    credentials : Login = new Login();

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    doLogin() {
        this.submitted.emit(this.credentials);
    }
}
```

**HTML of encapsulating element:**

```typescript
<login-form (submitted)="login($event)"></login-form>\
```

When I move the `EventEmitter` to the derived class, everything works like a charm. **What do I need to change to allow this to work?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such decorators in super-classes are not recognized by Angular.

You can enable them using the `@Component()` annotation

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  outputs: ['submitted'],
  inputs: ['...']
})
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5415

Comment: I don't have a `@Component` decorator on the inherited class because it is `abstract`. Can I still use this workaround?

Comment: You need to add it on the class that is actually used as component, it doesn't have any effect anywhere else. Also the `@Input()`, and `@Output()` decorators are redundant in super-classes (at least until the Angular team decides to support them in super-classes)

Comment: @günter-zöchbauer I have a 3rd party directive which I inherit. I want to catch its EventEmitter emit. How to do that? The suggested approaches do not work...

Comment: If you inherit (extend) you should be able to access it in code just by its name. Perhaps better to create a new question with the concrete code example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `@Component` decorator doesn't support inheritance (elements defined in the parent class). It takes into account only elements defined in the current decorated class.